# flutter error when using refactor extract flutter widget option in intellij idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea, dart, flutter

When I am trying to use 'Refactor - Extract - flutter widget' option in Intellij idea for refactoring a code in a widget, I am getting following error.

Server error: Invalid parameter 'params.kind'. Expected to be RefactoringKind; found ""EXTRACT_WIDGET"".

There is no solution available on internet for this. Please help

Flutter doctor output

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.371], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.0)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.3)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.22.2)
[√] Connected devices (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Please add the output of `flutter doctor` to your question. Do you have the latest IntelliJ/AS version and the latest Flutter plugin version?

Comment: I have added output of flutter doctor. please check it

Comment: I'd suggest to try `flutter channel master`. This feature is quite new. If it works there you can always try `dev` and `beta` again to see if the change landed there already as well.

Comment: its not working

Comment: What does that mean? You get the same error with `master` channel?

Comment: As Gunter says, check you have the latest IDEA and plugin. It works in Ultimate 2018.1.2 and Flutter plugin 24.1.2. Flutter doctor shows you are still on CE 2017.3. Try upgrading to CE 2018.1.2, and make sure you have the latest plugin.